# StremListener does't return data in JSON in tweepy

Tags: python, json, tweepy

My goal is to get the data from `def on_status(self, status):` in json format.
Right now I return data in something similar to JSON, but it's not JSON:

```
{'favorited': False, 'contributors': None, 'truncated': False, 'text': 'Lol. As long as you and Tsidi are awake, am not sleeping RT @TboyMP: @Fufu_Tinkies hambo lala wena!! LMAO!!', 'source_url': 'http://ubersocial.com', 'in_reply_to_status_id': None, 'user': <tweepy.models.User object at 0x1b4f3d0>, 'filter_level': 'medium', 'geo': None, 'id': 326808604013379586, 'favorite_count': 0, 'source': 'UberSocial for BlackBerry', 'lang': 'en', 'author': <tweepy.models.User object at 0x1b4f3d0>, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 23, 21, 23, 37), 'retweeted': False, 'coordinates': None, 'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None, 'entities': {'symbols': [], 'user_mentions': [{'id': 282499717, 'indices': [60, 67], 'id_str': '282499717', 'screen_name': 'TboyMP', 'name': 'Thulane Khanye'}, {'id': 157961325, 'indices': [69, 82], 'id_str': '157961325', 'screen_name': 'Fufu_Tinkies', 'name': 'Nomfundo'}], 'hashtags': [], 'urls': []}, 'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None, 'in_reply_to_screen_name': None, 'id_str': '326808604013379586', 'place': None, 'retweet_count': 0, 'in_reply_to_user_id': None}
```

As you can see it uses single quotes instead of double. The way I'm getting this is :

```
data = status.__getstate__()
```

However I can't `load` it with json module:  it gives me an error:

```
Encountered Exception: expected string or buffer
```

So how to remove data from there in JSON or convert it to JSON?

## UPDATE

I want to have something like this:

```
>>> data = '[{"fooo":"bar","something":"another bar"}]'
>>> ww = json.loads(data)
>>> ww[0]['fooo']
u'bar'
```

I'm expecting to get help in the way I can do this with `tweepy` data....
thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will write the raw json data from `def on_status(self, status):` to a file.

This solution was taken from [here](http://willsimm.co.uk/saving-tweepy-output-to-mongodb/) to add the raw json data to the status object, and [here](http://peter-hoffmann.com/2012/simple-twitter-streaming-api-access-with-python-and-oauth.html) as skeleton code to use the streaming functionality of tweepy.

```
@classmethod                    
def parse(cls, api, raw):
        status = cls.first_parse(api, raw)
        setattr(status, 'json', json.dumps(raw))
        return status

tweepy.models.Status.first_parse = tweepy.models.Status.parse
tweepy.models.Status.parse = parse

_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        print status.user.screen_name
        with codecs.open(os.path.join(_dir, 'tweets.json'), "a", 'utf-8') as textFile:
                textFile.write(status.json)
                textFile.write('\n')

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True # Don't kill the stream
```

I'm no Python expert, but it seems what's going on is that the parse method is being hot-patched with a new version, and then that new version is installed into the tweepy class hierarchy. The new version calls the old version, and then appends a json slot to the object returned from the original parse method.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a Python dictionary, to convert it to JSON use [`json.dumps()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps):

```
import json
json_data = json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: The structure that you printed in your question is a Python dictionary, which is the same thing that `json.loads()` will return.  You should be able to use whatever you already have the way you want to, for example `data['favorited']`, without needing to worry about any JSON conversion.

Comment: If I do something like : `data = things that I paste` I will get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: This works except that it doesn't seem to be recursive, so it doesn't drill into the User object for the 'user' key and get all of it's attributes. Instead, I get this error: `TypeError: <tweepy.models.User object at 0x10137a850> is not JSON serializable
`

Comment: @ClaytonStanley Sounds like your issue is a bit different, I would suggest asking a new question.